# How do you support large screen resolutions with website background images?

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

I have a website that I developed, but I just got a screenshot from someone who was looking at it on a 2560 x 1600 monitor and it looks kind of ridiculous. What is a reasonable upper limit for screen resolutions to support? I'm concerned about negatively impacting load time by adding a huge image. How can I deal with this properly?

Comment: I would create multiple versions of the background image at different sizes and use media queries to apply them as the viewport width increases. This site shows desktop screen size stats to help you pick a max width http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-resolution-ww-monthly-201510-201610-bar

Comment: You could also try scaling the image up 2x and setting JPG compression to 0% to save a few bytes https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/compressive-images.html

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1: Maximum width

Use a container div with the following CSS:

```
#innerbody {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Put all HTML in this container (wrap the container around all HTML), like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="innerbody">
  ... your page ...
  </div>
</body>
```

I would also add a nice subtle background color to the body, to mark where the 'page' ends, like this:

```
body {background: #eee;}
#innerbody {background: #fff;}
```

---

## Solution 2: Mask the quality

If you are only worried about the (poor) image quality, you can add the container div (from solution 1) and use this CSS to overlay a hatch (diagonal lines). This is trick is often used for low quality full-screen video, but also works for background images.

```
#innerbody {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(/hatch.png);
}
```

---

## Solution 3: Media queries

Got a big screen? Thou shall get a big image. Got a small screen? Thou shall get a small image. Sounds logical, right? You can achieve this by using media queries. This works like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background: url(small_image.jpg);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 501px) {
  body {
    background: url(medium_image.jpg);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) and (min-width: 1001px) {
  body {
    background: url(big_image.jpg);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 2001px) {
  body {
    background: url(really_big_image.jpg);
  }
}
```

For each screen size ONE of these media queries will be true. That image wil be served.

Answer (score 1):

To address your load time concern, one option is to use media queries so you can control the background image based on visitor viewport size. e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .div-with-background{
        background-image: url("background-sm.jpg");
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
   .div-with-background{
        background-image: url("background-md.jpg");
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1201px){
   .div-with-background{
        background-image: url("background-lg.jpg");
  }
}
```

> What is a reasonable upper limit for screen resolutions to support?

It depends on your visitors. If you use Google Analytics, you can get details on this by going to Users > Technology > Browser & OS and under 'Secondary Dimension' search for 'Screen Resolution'

Hope this helps!